# Python Tkinter: ¿Cómo puedo tener una ventana toplevel que esté siempre encima y se pueda minimizar?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy trabajando en una aplicación en python en donde tengo una ventana padre (app) y una ventana Toplevel. Quiero que la ventana toplevel se encuentre siempre sobre la ventana padre, por lo que utilizo el método `transient`, el problema es que al hacer esto, no me aparecen en la ventana toplevel los botones de minimizar ni agrandar, solo el de cerrar. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que estos botones aparezcan?, ¿o hay un método mejor para lograr esto?  Básicamente, esto es lo que tengo:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.geometry("200x200")

def nueva_ventana():
    nueva = Toplevel(app)
    nueva.transient(app)
    nueva.geometry("200x200")
    nueva.focus_set()

Button(app, text = "Crear ventana", command = nueva_ventana)

mainloop()
```

Específicamente me interesa poder minimizar la ventana, y que al minimizar la ventana toplevel, se minimicen ambas ventanas.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

#### Código

No, lamentablemente, tkinter no ofrece ninguna forma de lograr lo que buscas. Sin embargo, podemos hacerlo por nosotros mismos con algunos de los materiales de construcción que dicho modulo ofrece.

El código a continuación, crea una ventana principal. Luego, hacemos que con la tecla enter, se inicialize una ventana toplevel especial.

Nota: Está probado en Windows 11. No puedo garantizar que funcione en otros sistemas operativos.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MinimizableTrasient(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self["bg"] = "black"
        self.is_minimized = False

        self.transientize()

    def transientize(self):
        parent = self.nametowidget(self.winfo_parent())
        
        state = self.state()
        parent_state = parent.state()

        if(self.is_minimized):
            if(state == "normal"):
                parent.state(state)
                self.is_minimized = False
                
            elif(parent_state == "normal"):
                self.state(parent_state)
                self.is_minimized = False
        else:
            if(state == "iconic"):
                parent.state(state)
                self.is_minimized = True
            elif(parent_state == "iconic"):
                self.state(parent_state)
                self.is_minimized = True
            
        
        if(self.winfo_ismapped()):
            is_bellow_parent = int(self.tk.eval("wm stackorder {} isbelow {}".format(self, parent)))
            
            if(is_bellow_parent):
                self.lift(parent)

        self.after(1, self.set_window_over_parent)
        
root = tk.Tk()

root.bind("<Return>", lambda e:MinimizableTrasient(root))
```

#### Explicación de cada función

###### __init__

Esta función es llamada cuando se crea una instancia de clase (se la llama a la clase como si fuera una función).

Aquí, establecemos el valor inicial de is_minimized en False (asumimos que inicia siendo visible). Luego, llamamos a la función transientize para inciar su ejecución durante la existencia de la ventana.

###### transientize

Esta es la función que hace la magia. Ocurren las siguientes cosas:

- Obtenemos la ventana padre y los estados del toplevel y su padre.
- Si el booleano is_minimized es True y alguno de los estados pasó a ser "normal", es decir, son visibles, entonces establecemos el mismo estado de la ventana visible a la otra ventana. Y a is_minimized en False.
- Si el booleano is_minimized es False y alguno de los estados pasó a ser "iconic", es decir, se minimizó alguna ventana, establecemos el mismo estado de la ventana minimizada a la otra ventana. Y a is_minimized en True.
- Lo anterior basicamente significa "si una está minimizada, minimiza la otra, si alguna fue restaurada, restaura la otra".

Lo que sigue, se encarga de hacer que el toplevel siempre se dibuje sobre la ventana padre, y se ejecuta solo si nuestro toplevel especial está "mapeado", o sea, es visible.

Si ejecutamos todo el tiempo el método que ubica la ventana arriba de su padre, se ve un efecto horrible de parpadeo. Así, que opté por crear un condicional que solo ejecute dicho método cuando la ventana de hecho está por debajo de la ventana padre.

- El método que verifica esto no está implementado de forma segura en tkinter, lo que nos obliga a usar el eval del iterprete de tkinter. El comando usado va a ser `wm stackorder {ventana} isbelow {ventana padre}`. Que devuelve la cadena '0' si la ventana está arriba de su padre, y '1' si la ventana está por debajo. Notese las comillas, son cadenas, no números. Por lo que las convertimos en números con la función int. Y ahora podemos dejar que Python transforme eso en un booleano.
- Si la ventana está por debajo, la movemos arriba de la ventana padre.
- Finalmente, mandamos a que la función se ejecute dentro de un milisegundo. Esto dará como resultado que la función se ejecute cada un milisegundo hasta que automaticamente sea cancelada por el cierre de la ventana.